# design custom android lock pattern similar app with custom functionality

Tags: android

I want to create android application that contain some points and user can connect the points with drawing line between them (similar to android lock pattern but there is points in custom position and user can add line after drawing a pattern).
I don't know where should I start to search about and what to search for this requirement.
How should I design and code for this?

any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally find the solution that use a custom view. In a similar case please use the code below:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class ConnectDotsView extends View {

private Bitmap mBitmap;
private Canvas mCanvas;
private Path mPath;
private Paint mPaint;
private Paint mCirclePaint;
private Point startPoint;
private List<Point> selectPoints;
private static final int TOUCH_TOLERANCE_DP = 30;
private static final int BACKGROUND = 0xFFFFFF;
private List<Point> mPoints = new ArrayList<Point>();
private int mTouchTolerance;

public ConnectDotsView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mCanvas = new Canvas();
    mPath = new Path();
    selectPoints = new ArrayList<Point>();
    initPaint();
}

public ConnectDotsView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mCanvas = new Canvas();
    mPath = new Path();
    selectPoints = new ArrayList<Point>();
    initPaint();
}

public ConnectDotsView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    mCanvas = new Canvas();
    mPath = new Path();
    selectPoints = new ArrayList<Point>();
    initPaint();
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int width, int height, int oldWidth, int oldHeight) {
    super.onSizeChanged(width, height, oldWidth, oldHeight);
    clear();

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(BACKGROUND);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, null);
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);

    //Draw Points
    for (Point point : mPoints) {
        canvas.drawCircle(point.x, point.y, 16, mCirclePaint);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touch_start(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touch_move(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touch_up(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            touch_up(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
    }
    return true;
}

private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
    startPoint = getFeasiblePoint(x, y);
}

private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
    clear();
    Point p = getFeasiblePoint(x, y);
    if (startPoint == null) {
        startPoint = p;
    } else if (p != null) {
        if (p != startPoint) {
            mPath.moveTo(startPoint.x, startPoint.y);
            mPath.lineTo(p.x, p.y);
            selectPoints.add(startPoint);
            selectPoints.add(p);
            startPoint = p;
        }
    } else {
        mCanvas.drawLine(startPoint.x, startPoint.y, x, y, mPaint);
    }
}

private void touch_up(float x, float y) {
    clear();
    Point p = getFeasiblePoint(x, y);
    if (startPoint == null) {
        startPoint = p;
    } else if (p != null) {
        if (p != startPoint) {
            mPath.moveTo(startPoint.x, startPoint.y);
            mPath.lineTo(p.x, p.y);
            selectPoints.add(startPoint);
            selectPoints.add(p);
            startPoint = p;
        }
    }
}

public void setPaint(Paint paint) {
    this.mPaint = paint;
}

public Bitmap getBitmap() {
    return mBitmap;
}

private void clear() {
    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mBitmap.eraseColor(BACKGROUND);
    mCanvas.setBitmap(mBitmap);
    invalidate();
}

private Point getFeasiblePoint(float x, float y) {
    for (Point point : mPoints) {
        if (x > (point.x - mTouchTolerance) && x < (point.x + mTouchTolerance)) {
            if (y > (point.y - mTouchTolerance) && y < (point.y + mTouchTolerance)) {
                return point;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public List<Point> getPoints() {
    return mPoints;
}

public void setPoints(List<Point> points) {
    this.mPoints = points;
}

public List<Point> getSelectPoints() {
    return selectPoints;
}

public void Reset() {
    selectPoints = new ArrayList<Point>();
    mPath.reset();
    clear();
}

private void initPaint() {
    //Paint
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);
    //CirclePaint
    mCirclePaint = new Paint();
    mCirclePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mCirclePaint.setDither(true);
    mCirclePaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    mCirclePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    mCirclePaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mCirclePaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mCirclePaint.setStrokeWidth(12);
    //Others
    mTouchTolerance = Utility.dp2px(getContext(), TOUCH_TOLERANCE_DP);
}
}
```

Comment: Tell me at least How to use it.. I did but nothing is showing on the screen.

Comment: @NikunjkumarKapupara use it as a custom view in your layout and initialize it with some points on the onCreate method of behind code.

Answer (score 0):

this library will helps you, created app with this

https://github.com/Pi-Developers/Pi-Locker

more reference : https://github.com/n3tr/DrawPoints